# Apache 2.4 and php-fpm does not trigger apache http basic auth for php pages

Tags: apache, proxy, php, fastcgi, centos7

I am sure this is a question which has been asked somewhere, if so excuse me, but googling around did not give me anything tangible.

**Here is my scenario:**

I am protecting a web directory with apache http basic auth. So I have my .htaccess in the root folder and my httpd.conf is configure to override all so that it takes the .htaccess into consideration. The content of my .htaccess is as follows:

AuthType Basic

AuthName "test"

AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.test_pass

Require valid-user

.test_pass has been set up with htpasswd successfully. When accessing the web root folder via the browser or any html file I get the authentication pop up correctly. Using the password gives me the expected access.

But when I access a php page, the authentication pop up does not appear and the php page renders.

Here is my set up:

- Apache Version: 2.4.6
- php-fpm: PHP 5.4.16 (fpm-fcgi) with Zend Engine v2.4.0
- Using proxypass from proxy_fcgi_module (shared) for the communication
  between apache 2.4 and php-fpm
- Also I am not using socket connections because apache 2.4.6 does not
  support it
- My proxypass setting is as follows and works pretty well:
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$
  fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1

I need to be able to set a username/password authentication via apache basic auth which protects every files including php files in the directory.

I am using opensource softwares; therefore modifying the software codes is the very last resort.

Is there a work around/solution for php-fpm and mod_proxy_fcgi?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of research I understood that the reason that this occurs is because the ProxyPassMatch directive is the first directive to be processed, and this causes apache to ignore the other directives for the .php extensions.

To be able to use other apache directives with php-fpm via the proxy_fcgi_module one should rather use the filesmatch directive instead of proxypassmatch.

The syntax is as follows:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```