# Basic authentication in vhost in PHP FPM

Tags: php, basic-authentication, fpm

I want to setup a basic authentication based vhost for where apache PHP handler is FastCGI(FPM). I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033794/apache-2-4-and-php-fpm-does-not-trigger-apache-http-basic-auth-for-php-pages), but not sure it is same what I doing or not.

Server and SW details:
CentOS 6.9
Apache 2.4 - compiled with source
PHP 5.6.6 - compiled with source

I have configured PHP with FPM and running PHP as :

```
php-fpm -y /usr/local/php/php/fpm/php-fpm.conf -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I have some pools which:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen = 127.0.0.1:9002 ..
```

and so on

and my vhost configured as :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/webserver/web"
    ServerName spectrumenterprise.jnj.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/webserver/web>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI +MultiViews    
        AllowOverride All    
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user    
        Require all granted     
        <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteOptions InheritBefore
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9007/var/www/html/webserver/web/$1 [L,P]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>        
    ErrorLog "logs/spectrumenterprise.jnj.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/spectrumenterprise.jnj.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

If something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution,

I have an .htaccess at webroot, I added

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/site1/web/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Require all granted
```

after

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
```

added the .htpasswd file at same location of .htaccess (in my case /var/www/html/site1/web/)

restart pool and apache

```
pkill -o php-fpm
php-fpm -y /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k restart
```